# How do I output the positive elements in the vector in reverse order?

Tags: c++

I have the correct answer but it's just in the wrong order and I'm not sure how to reverse it. I can't add anything before `for (int i = 1; i < inputVector.size(); i++) {`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int i;
   vector<int> inputVector;
   int value;

   cin >> value;
   while (value != -1) {
      inputVector.push_back(value);
      cin >> value;
   }

   for (int i = 1; i < inputVector.size(); i++) {
      if (inputVector[i] > 0) {
         cout << inputVector[i] << " " << endl;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `push_front()`?

Comment: `std::reverse(iinputVector.begin(), inputVector.end());`? `for (auto element : inputVector | std::views::reverse) { ... }`?

Comment: @JeJo You can rewrite this to work with empty vectors without an additional `if`: `for(auto i = inputVector.size(); i > 0;) { --i; ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
   for (int i = 1; i < inputVector.size(); i++) {
      if (inputVector[i] > 0) {
         cout << inputVector[i] << " " << endl;
      }
   }
```

Because your index `i` starts at `1`, you are actually skipping the first element at `inputVector[0]`. I'm not sure why. But to print the list in reverse, you can adjust the index value by subtracting `i` from the index of the last element (size - 1).

```
   for (size_t i = 0; i < inputVector.size(); i++) {
      size_t j = inputVector.size() - 1 - i;
      if (inputVector[j] > 0) {
         cout << inputVector[j] << " " << endl;
      }
   }
```

Vector also has a reverse iterator. So you can also do this:

```
for (auto itor = inputVector.rbegin(); itor != inputVector.rend(); itor++) {

    int value = *itor;
    if (value > 0) {
       cout << value << " " << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient given your contraints.

```cpp
 for (int i = inputVector.size() - 1; i > 0 ; i++)
      if (inputVector[i] > 0) 
         cout << inputVector[i] << " " << endl;
```

Comment: if `inputVector.size()` is 0, bad things happen. And if it doesn't, it won't print the inputVector[0].

Comment: Should `i > 0` handle this case?

Comment: Use `for (size_t i = inputVector.size();  i > 0 ; i--)` and then within the loop, deference `inputVector[i-1]`

Comment: Does the question require printing `inputVector[0]` as it starts from index 1?

Answer (score 0):

Another good approach using the convenience functions in `<algorithm>` is [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) (and for C++20 [std::ranges::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/for_each)). There you simply have to pass the reverse iterators as arguments and a short lambda function to select (and output in your case) the positive values. This boils down to:

```cpp
  std::for_each (rbegin(inputVector), rend(inputVector), 
                  [](const int i) {
                    if (i > 0) { std::cout << i << '\n'; }
                  });
```

A short example in your case would be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  
  std::vector<int> inputVector { -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
  
  std::for_each (rbegin(inputVector), rend(inputVector), 
                  [](const int i) {
                    if (i > 0) { std::cout << i << '\n'; }
                  });
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/find_if_positive
3
2
1
```

Whether you do it manually by looping or using one of the functions C++ provides, you will be doing the same thing. Worth knowing how to do it either way.